# Encrypt json file while sending it to External System

Tags: apex, class, encryption, crypto

i have custom object with the json file attached in it.

i need to encrypt it while sending this file to external system. how can i achieve this in sfdc

Comment: While sending the file impress that you just need to use https. If you need to store the data at the far end securely, then you need encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a finer level of encryption you can opt for Apex Crypto Class. It provides methods for creating digests, message authentication codes, and signatures, as well as encrypting and decrypting information. For more details regarding cryto class methods click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm)